# Си. Как сконвертить byte[] в unsigned char* ?

Tags: массивы, c

Никак не придумаю как сконвертить байтовый массив в `unsigned char*`. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: 1) а какого типа ваши байты? случайно не `unsigned char`?  
2) массив в C почти ничем не отличается от указателя на первый (то есть нулевой) элемент, более того, он неявно в него преобразовывается.

Comment: байты типа char

Comment: А где такие байты дают?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Наверно как то так.

```
#define SIZE = 10
int i = 0;
byte array[SIZE];
unsigned char *ptr = malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * SIZE);

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    ptr[i] = (unsigned char *)array[i];
```

Так же можно попробовать просто создать указатель на unsigned char и с помощью него управлять вашим массивом, но насчет этого у не уверен что возможно.

```
byte array[10];
unsigned char *ptr;

ptr = (unsigned char *)array;
```

Comment: А почему не просто

    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char *)array;

?

Comment: Опередил ) Пока редактировал, если правда то не уверен что элементы массива к которым будут обращаться через данный указатель будут типа unsigned char. Мы же вроде как тока указатель преобразовали.

Comment: @Roman: ну, `signed`- и `undisgned`-вариант `char`'ов взаимозаменяемы: объект в памяти один и тот же (байт информации), просто арифметические операции и вывод ведут себя по-другому.

Comment: ИМХО, вместо `(unsigned char *)` лучше `static_cast<unsigned char *>`

Comment: @gecube: не, вопрос же по чистому C.

Comment: да, мне на AVR Studio требовалось

Comment: А какой там компилятор? Часто используют gcc, поэтому хедеры вполне стандартные. (Да и IAR вряд ли можно обвинить в новаторском подходе). Так что вопрос из моего комментария выше: где такие byte дают (в каком *.h файле описан тип byte, и как)?